# SwitchMap ist not a function

Tags: rxjs, electron

My project layout is a pretty simple [electron-webpack project structure](https://webpack.electron.build/project-structure). In my project I use `rxjs`, `react-redux` and `react-redux-typescript`. At the beginning I used to start my project with `electron-forge start` and build it using `electron-builder`. I changed my project layout so I can use `electron-webpack start` to start my project. When I start my project with `electron-forge start` everything works correctly but when I start it using `electron-webpack dev` it gives me [this stacktrace](https://pastebin.com/rkLxRr5F).

In both cases (`electron-forge start` and `electron-webpack dev`) it is the exact same codebase except the project structure.

My RXJS imports look like so:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/operators/switchMap'
```

I also tried using this import style

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'
```

Comment: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'`

Comment: My bad I seperated my rxjs includes in a seperate file, but I already did import switchMap like that. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

[martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310726/martin) is right, you've misspelled import statement, it should be `operator`, not `operators`

So, instead of this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operators/switchMap'
```

Do this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap
```

Comment: As I wrote in my question I used the same code with electron-forge ... It's just a spelling mistake in my question